# Why I keep geting my Date wrong on Google Sheets?

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

folks.

I am cleaning a dataset however in the Date row I get a strange number when I convert it do Date.

I have this:

[image]

And I get this:

[image]

What I wanted is dd-mm-yyyy.

What I tried:

I went to More Formats and manually separated the date, but it is still not recognised "Date".

[image]

I know this must be very basic, but I ave looked everywhere and couldnt find a solution.

Comment: can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Comment: Yes! There you go. @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mfgWbidFp9ys60cQIrpyMUX4azapVLzumaceMqe62Cg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think your issue is that you have your date as `="20171017"`. Namely it's a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the "date" in your D column is a string /plain text
you will need to convert it into date with helper column

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(DATE(LEFT(D2:D; 4); MID(D2:D; 5; 2); RIGHT(D2:D; 2))))
```